# Случаться и родительный падеж

Tags: грамматика, падежи

> Но **ничего такого** всё же не случилось.

(В. Березин, *Путевые знаки*)

Но я бы сказал вместо этого предложения

> Но **ничто такое** всё же не случилось.

Есть ли разница между этими предложениями? Или, может, моё совсем неправильно?

Comment: Допустим только первый вариант. Так как Вы предлагаете, ни один русский человек никогда не скажет.

Comment: А почему точно второй вариант неправильный?

Comment: Не случилось ничего.. Какого? Такого. Я увидел нечто.. Какое? Такое.

Comment: Вот даже затрудняюсь сказать почему. Грамматически-то всё верно, но тем не менее никто так не говорит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Рассмотрим Ваш пример. Он не является частным, то есть, связанным с лексическими особенностями глагола *случаться*(несов.)-*случиться*(сов.)

Пример сводится к схеме: `N_obj + не + V`

Фактически, вопрос сводится к следующему. В каком падеже ставить прямой объект при глаголе с отрицанием?

```
  Но ничего такого всё же не случилось.
    └─────┬───────┘      └─────┬──────┘
       object,               глагол 
      Род.падеж            с отрицанием
```

**История вопроса.**
Она довольно давняя, вот например, [обсуждение его А.Пушкиным](https://books.google.com/books?id=UuN6AgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA348&ots=R576YiqjJS&pg=PA348#v=onepage&q&f=false).

**Ответ краткий.**
[**§ 2667.**](http://rusgram.narod.ru/2661-2673.html#2667) *При переходных глаголах с отрицанием сильноуправляемое имя со знач. объекта может иметь форму род. или вин. п.*
§ 2668 гласит: Родительный падеж обязателен в следующих случаях ...; пункт (4): ...когда позицию имени со знач. объекта занимает местоимение `ничто`.

**Ответ развернутый.**

Однако, есть примеры с винительным падежом в литературе:

```
  ... но тогда ничто такое ему не будет опасно. [Н.Лесков]

  ... ничто не поддерживало въ нихъ такихъ воспоминаний,
     ничто такое не бросалось имъ въ глаза, ... [Н.Костомаров]
```

Следовательно, законом или правилом это назвать нельзя. Можно поступить как в физике, там, если нет логически безупречного объяснения, то класс явлений объявляют физическим эффектом :)

`Ничто` называют местоименным словом. Буквально, слово/термин *"местоимение"* можно прочитать *вместо-имени. (a word used instead of a name.)* Или — *на месте имени. (a substitute word or proxy.)* То есть, вместо конкретного "наименования/имени" используют обобщающий термин-слово.

Если `ничто` это (в)местоимение, грамматически не отличимое от имени, а имена у нас существительные, то есть, неотличимое от существительного, то это *обобщающий-термин-вместо-имени* конкретного "существительного". Тогда (в)местоимение `ничего` можно считать местоименным словом `ничто`, стоящим в родительном падеже.

Мы видим ещё одно (в)местоимение — `такой.` Это *термин-вместо-имени* конкретного *"прилагательного (lit.: a word used for adding on)"*.

Почему предпочитают родительный падеж? Вот как объясняет родительный падеж при глаголе с отрицанием Розенталь:

> Д.Э. Розенталь. Русский язык. 2005
>
> 1. Форма родительного падежа подчеркивает отрицание: *Угрюмых и серьёзных фигур их не терплю (Л.); Он не любил этого города (М.Г.).*
>      Это общее положение конкретизируется рядом условий, наличие которых
>      приводит к явному преобладанию формы родительного падежа дополнения
>      при переходном глаголе с отрицанием:
> 2. отрицание усиливается
>      частицей `ни` или местоимением либо местоимением или наречием, в состав
>      которого входит указанная частица: *Ни подкупы, ни запугивания, ни
>      насилия, к которым прибегали судовладельцы, не сломили боевого духа
>      итальянских моряков (Газ.); Никогда никому не доверял своей тайны
>      (Ч.); Никто не видел такого тяжелого и скверного сна (М.Г.);*

И следующий Ваш пример. Попробуем разобраться, почему предпочитают родительный падеж.

```
  Но ничто такое всё же не случилось.
```

Этот пример мы перепишем так, чтобы местоимение можно было использовать с именем одушевленным:

```
  Но ничто(никого) такое всё же не нашлось.
     └─────┬─────┘    \   
      Винительный      \___ не согласуется с винительным падежом
         падеж              для местоимения `никого`
```

Мы переписали для того, чтобы показать проблему: в винительном падеже местоимение `ничто/никто` примет форму `ничто/никого.`

Выбором *одушевленное/неодушевленное* вносится дополнительная дифференциация для винительного падежа, необходимы два словосочетания `ничто такое / никого такого.` Родительный же падеж, одной формой, а значит, более экономно, передает более общее значение. Одно слово `такого` и для одушевл., и для неодушевл.

Для говорящего легче формулировать более общие утверждения. А поскольку русский язык относится к классу синтетических языков (на другой стороне аналитические, например, английский/китайский), тот, кто говорит/пишет, совершает больше работы, чем тот, кто читает написанное.

Идя по пути наименьшего сопротивления, у носителей языка, видимо, и сложился навык использовать форму родительного падежа, `ничего/никого такого + не + глагол`.

**Почему существует два падежа?** Выбором падежа мы устраняем омонимию (двусмысленность):

```
    Винительный       |       Родительный
----------------------+-----------------------
                      |
  Ты вилку не взял.   |   Ты вилки не взял.  
                      |        \
                      |         ед.ч. или мн.ч. ?
                      |         
  Мы не споем песню.  |   Мы не споем песни. 
                      |                  \
                      |            ед.ч. или мн.ч. ?  
                      |
  Не построили дом.   |   Не построили дома.  
                      |                  \
                      |                внутри дома?
                      |                этого дома?
                      |     на письме: много домов?
                      |       На письме необходимо 
                      |        обозначить ударение.
```

Comment: Но на русском языке часто используется отрицание с винительным падежом, на пример: "Не остановить мечт**у**". Но ища примеры для этого, я нашёл контрпример: "Ден**ег** не взял". Почему иногда используется винительный, а иногда родительный падеж?

Comment: @marmistrz  *Почему существует два падежа?* -- добавлено в ответ.

Comment: Значит винительный падеж используется всегда тогда, когда неясно или это родительный или винительный (именительный) падеж; т.е. использование винительного падежа - это исключение?

Comment: Впрочем: "не носит ответственности" и нет "не носит ответственность". А здесь правильный вариант "неясный" - "ответвственности" - это может быть Р.ед.ч. или И.В.мн.ч.

Comment: И было ли бы это правильно сказать "Не остановить мечт**ы**"?

Comment: Когда (а) выбор Вин/Род существует, и (б) люди живые и творческие, то (в) нельзя сказать, что Вин.п. используется "тогда и только тогда, если...". Это слишком математично. Люди не успеют проанализировать такое условие сознательно. В разговорной речи такие ошибки (двусмысленностей) часты, я замечаю и у себя. Люди полагаются на свой автоматизм, на субъективное "чувство языка". А вот литературные редакторы, они уже могут сознательно применять правила, исправлять/направлять речь. Мы сами выступаем для себя редакторами, когда прочитываем написанное и исправляем. В речи часты повторы-исправления.

Comment: Род/Вин  `Не несёт ответственности / не несёт ответственность`. Очень редко можно встреть Им.п. множ.ч. *ответственности*, поэтому здесь равносильно, что употребить, и в разговоре на 99% поймут как ед.ч. Во множественном числе Род.п. будет `не несёт полномочий и ответственностей`. /// Да, "Не остановить мечты" — правильно, но двусмысленно: *этой_одной_мечты? / эти_мечты?*. Уверен, такая ошибка в речи будет часта. Но литературный редактор (мы сами в письме) этого допустить не должен.

Comment: @marmistrz Если коротко, то "не" с родительным падежом - это старая форма; "не" с винительным - относительное нововведение (лет, эдак, двести). Окончательного размежевания между ними до сих пор не произошло. Есть много случаев, когда в современном языке допустим только один из этих падежей, и еще больше - когда оба. http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/?rub=otr

Answer (score 1):

Ваш вариант необычен, но не является неверным. 
Он передает более категоричное отрицание и конкретное.
Сравните с одушевленным вариантом. Никто не заходил - никого не заходило.

Грамматику не буду сейчас разбирать. Скорее всего это действительно винительный падеж.

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае частица *ни* меняет падеж (и тип предложения с обычного на безличное).

*Что-то такое случилось.*

*Ничего такого не случилось.*

Т.е. ваш вариант (именительный падеж) используется, когда нет отрицания. Ещё пример:

*Есть деньги. Нет денег.*

Comment: Позвольте поинтересоваться: в каком из примеров в OP (original post) используется Именительный падеж?

Comment: "Но ничто такое всё же не случилось"

Comment: Как подтвердить, или чем проверим, что это Именительный падеж?

Comment: Подставить любое слово, которое склоняется. Например, *авария случилась", "аварии не случилось". Иностранцу в голову не придёт даже теоретически использовать винительный падеж с глаголом "случилось"

Comment: А творительный, например, с "не случилось"? Придет в голову?

Comment: Кто их знает, этих нерусских

Comment: Каким образом не случилось Вам познакомиться с примерами, где употребляется `Noun_ins + не случилось`?

Comment: Так карты легли