# Каким правилом определяется какая буква, а или ы, будет во множественном числе существительного

Tags: множественное-число

Часто есть сомнения о том, как правильно существительно будет писаться во множественном числе. Например:

Корпуса или корпусы.
Сервера или серверы.
Конвееры, но ведь может быть и конвеера? Хотя понятно что это не верно.

При чем я знаю, что как в примере со словом "корпус", в зависимости от значения, будет и так и так. Так как же узнать какой вариант правильный? Есть ли вообще какое-то логическое правило, определяющее форму окончания? Спасибо.

Comment: См. [Why does дом become дома instead of домы?](http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/10763/why-does-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC-become-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0-instead-of-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%8B) Боюсь, что разложить все по полочкам не выйдет.

Comment: Есть целая глава у Розенталя с несколькими группами слов на эту тему. Вопрос слишком широкий.

Comment: Добавлю, что "сервера", "корпуса", "конвеера" -- это изначально недопустимые формы слов, которые со временем стали нормой. Так же, как вместе с правильным "квартАлы" произносят "квАрталы".

Comment: Думаю, самый неоднозначный случай с договоры - договора. По крайней мере, в современной устной речи.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Так как же узнать какой вариант правильный?

Посмотреть в словаре: [корпус](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81&all=x), [договор](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80&all=x)

Точнее, это "нормативный". А что еще может означать "правильный"?

> Есть ли вообще какое-то логическое правило, определяющее форму окончания?

Вот что пишет по этому поводу Корней Чуковский в книге "Живой как жизнь" (1961 г.):

> Такое же недоумение вызывала во мне новоявленная форма: выбора́
>   (вместо вы́боры), договора́ (вместо догово́ры), лектора́ (вместо
>   ле́кторы). В ней слышалось мне что-то залихватское, бесшабашное,
>   забубенное, ухарское. Напрасно я утешал себя тем, что эту форму уже
>   давно узаконил русский литературный язык. — Ведь, — говорил я себе, —
>   еще Ломоносов двести лет тому назад утверждал, что русские люди
>   предпочитают окончание «а» «скучной букве» «и» в окончаниях слов:
>   облака, острова, леса вместо облаки, островы, лесы. Кроме того, прошло
>   лет сто, а пожалуй, и больше, с тех пор, как русские люди перестали
>   говорить и писать: домы, докторы, учители, профессоры, слесари,
>   юнкеры, пекари, писари, флигели и охотно заменили их формами: дома́,
>   учителя́, профессора́, слесаря́, флигеля́, юнкера́, пекаря́ и т.д.
>   Мало того: следующее поколение придало ту же залихватскую форму новым
>   десяткам слов, таким, как: бухгалтеры, томы, катеры, тополи, лагери,
>   дизели. Стали говорить и писать:бухгалтера́, тома́, катера́, тополя́,
>   лагеря́, дизеля́ и т.д. Если бы Чехов, например, услышал слово тома́,
>   он подумал бы, что речь идет о французском композиторе Амбруазе Тома́.
>   Казалось бы, довольно. Но нет. Пришло новое поколение, и я услыхал от
>   него: шофера́, автора́, библиотекаря́, сектора́, прибыля́, отпуска́. И
>   еще через несколько лет: выхода́, супа́, матеря́, дочеря́, секретаря́,
>   плоскостя́, скоростя́, ведомостя́, возраста́, площадя́. III Всякий раз
>   я приходил к убеждению, что протестовать против этих для меня
>   уродливых слов бесполезно. Я мог сколько угодно возмущаться, выходить
>   из себя, но нельзя же было не видеть, что здесь на протяжении столетия
>   происходит какой-то безостановочный стихийный процесс замены
>   безударного окончания ы(и) сильно акцентированным окончанием а(я). И
>   кто же поручится, что наши правнуки не станут говорить и писать:
>   крана́, актера́, медведя́, желудя́. Наблюдая за пышным расцветом этой
>   ухарской формы, я не раз утешал себя тем, что эта форма завладевает
>   главным образом такими словами, которые в данном профессиональном
>   (иногда очень узком) кругу упоминаются чаще всего: форма торта́
>   существует только в кондитерских, супа́ — в ресторанных кухнях,
>   площадя́ — в домовых управлениях, трактора́ и скоростя́ — у
>   трактористов. Пожарные говорят: факела́. Электрики — кабеля́ и
>   штепселя́. Певчие в «Спевке» Слепцова: концерта́, тенора́ (1863). Не
>   станем сейчас заниматься вопросом, желателен ли этот процесс или нет,
>   об этом разговор впереди, а покуда нам важно отметить один
>   многознаменательный факт: все усилия бесчисленных ревнителей чистоты
>   языка остановить этот бурный процесс или хотя бы ослабить его до сих
>   пор остаются бесплодными. Если бы мне даже и вздумалось сейчас
>   написать «то́мы Шекспира», я могу быть заранее уверенным, что в моей
>   книге напечатают: «тома́ Шекспира», так как то́мы до того устарели,
>   что современный читатель почуял бы в них стилизаторство, жеманность,
>   манерничание.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, со словом «конвейер» больше подходит «ы»: конвейер

Все конвейеры запущены.
Все серверы подключены.
Все корпуса изготовлены.